"Name cannot be blank" error when creating entity despite providing name in request body in Spring Boot
I'm working on a Spring Boot application where I need to create a Data Center using a REST API. However, I keep encountering an error stating "Name cannot be blank" even though I am providing the name field in the request body.

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(AdminConstants.API_V1_DATA_CENTER_ROOT_URL)
public class DataCenterRestApi {
  /**
   * Create data center. if user is not admin, it will be rejected.
   *
   * @param dataCenterDto data center dto
   * @return if the operation is success
   */
  @Loggable
  @PreAuthorize(AUTHORIZE + " and hasRole('ADMIN')")
  @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<OperationStatus> createDataCenter(@RequestBody DataCenterDto dataCenterDto) {
    // Log incoming data
    Logger.getLogger(DataCenterRestApi.class.getName())
        .info("Creating data center: " + dataCenterDto);

    if (Objects.isNull(dataCenterDto.getName())) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name cannot be blank");
    }

    dataCenterService.createDataCenter(dataCenterDto);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(OperationStatus.SUCCESS);
  }
}

And here is my DataCenterDto class:
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true, callSuper = true)
public class DataCenterDto extends BaseDto implements Serializable {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6342630857637389028L;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String publicId;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @NotBlank(message = DataCenterConstants.BLANK_NAME)
    private String name;

    @Email(message = DataCenterConstants.INVALID_EMAIL)
    private String email;

    private String phone;

    // Address-related fields
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String district;
    private String address;
    private String postalCode;

    // Other details
    private String description;
    private String ownerCompany;

    // Location-related fields
    @DecimalMin(value = DataCenterConstants.LATITUDE_MIN, message = DataCenterConstants.LATITUDE_RANGE)
    @DecimalMax(value = DataCenterConstants.LATITUDE_MAX, message = DataCenterConstants.LATITUDE_RANGE)
    private BigDecimal latitude;

    @DecimalMin(value = DataCenterConstants.LONGITUDE_MIN, message = DataCenterConstants.LONGITUDE_RANGE)
    @DecimalMax(value = DataCenterConstants.LONGITUDE_MAX, message = DataCenterConstants.LONGITUDE_RANGE)
    private BigDecimal longitude;

    // Activation status
    private boolean enabled;
}

I am sending the following curl request:
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/datacenter' \
  -H 'accept: application/hal+json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN_HERE' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "id": 0,
  "version": 0,
  "createdAt": "2024-12-19T06:25:54.376Z",
  "createdBy": "string",
  "updatedAt": "2024-12-19T06:25:54.376Z",
  "updatedBy": "string",
  "publicId": "string",
  "name": "Test Data Center",
  "email": "test@gmail.com",
  "phone": "12345678901",
  "country": "Turkey",
  "city": "Istanbul",
  "district": "Besiktas",
  "address": "Test Address",
  "postalCode": "34020",
  "description": "Test Description",
  "ownerCompany": "Test Company",
  "latitude": 90,
  "longitude": 180,
  "enabled": true
}'

Despite providing the name field, I receive the following error:
Name cannot be blank


2024-12-19T09:27:12.146+03:00  INFO 4016 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.ziyaret.annotation.impl.MethodLogger   : => Starting -  execution(DataCenterRestApi.createDataCenter(..)) args: [DataCenterDto(publicId=null, name=null, email=null, phone=null, country=null, city=null, district=null, address=null, postalCode=null, description=null, ownerCompany=null, latitude=null, longitude=null, enabled=false)]
2024-12-19T09:27:12.150+03:00  INFO 4016 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.ziyaret.web.rest.v1.DataCenterRestApi  : Creating data center: DataCenterDto(publicId=null, name=null, email=null, phone=null, country=null, city=null, district=null, address=null, postalCode=null, description=null, ownerCompany=null, latitude=null, longitude=null, enabled=false)
2024-12-19T09:27:12.152+03:00  WARN 4016 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name cannot be blank]

I don't have data in the database. What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it?
Any help or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

have you debugged to check which values actually arrive?

Why is there an @Validated as that serves a totally different purpose, ditch it. Why is there no @(Rest)Controller on your class? Or is this some dumbed down version not showing the actual issue?

@M.Deinum When I ask a question I try to Valid and Validate Annotation to learn and solve this problem. I added it to the latest version of my code.

HTTP 409 is weird, I would expect a 400 or 500 if this would be a validation error (which you aren't using as you removed the @Valid from the method, not sure why).

Have you tested without the @Loggable and @PreAuthorize?

Yes, but I get the same error. All other methods working well but the data center create endpoint not working. When I delete a valid annotation I'm facing a 409 status code with the same message.

Well if it works, then either you aren't showing what you are actually doing or the JSON you are sending isn't actual json and thus not parsable leading to null fields. You are also using Lombok is that actually working and generating the setters/getters? Are you using the proper @RequestBody annotation (you didn't include the imports so we don't know)

Actually I'm using same JSON for this problem. For the DTO I have a baseDto: `java @Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class BaseDto {
private Long id;
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include private int version;
private LocalDateTime createdAt;
private String createdBy;
private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
private String updatedBy;
}
`. I'm using lombok Getter and Setter and working good. Just create method not working and I share my Dto. I can share my entity but not parse data from swagger.

@M.Deinum, thank you for your help. I found my problem. I have an autocomplete library and I added the wrong library for RequestBody. After I control right now I get data. Thank you for your help.
